# spherical coordinates to find the triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Use spherical coordinates to evaluate the triple integral

[image]

where E is the region bounded by the spheres [image]
 and [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform to spherical coordinates to obtain the integral
$$
I_E = \int_2 ^3 \int_0 ^ {2\pi} \int_0 ^\pi \frac{e^{-\rho^2}}{\rho} \rho^2 \sin \phi \, \mathrm{d} \phi  \, \mathrm{d} \theta  \, \mathrm{d} \rho = \cdots
$$
To evaluate the integral, you can employ Fubini's Theorem to get the value quite handily. I believe the result is $I_E = \frac{2 \pi}{e^4} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{e^5} \right)$.

Comment: @user131040 No problem! I am glad that it was helpful - when just learning multivariable, the different coordinate maps can seem more foreboding at first, I am happy that this was useful for you!